# Gaps between tiles in billinear option for NetCDF in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, tiles

[image]I am serving a WMS layer- temperature- of a NetCDF by GeoServer 2.22 to Leaflet app. I choose billinear interpolation method in geoserver and I have the gaps below between my tiles. It happens the same with bicubic, not with nearest neighbour.I use netcdf plugin for publishing temperature and more other variables, native srs 4326 and forced 3857.
[image]

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. Also, we need to know more about the input (gdalinfo output) and how you set up the layer and how you are drawing the layer in JS

Comment: @Ian Turton, thank you, I have developer logging level, but the issue is in geoserver.  when I use for example the layer preview -openlayers-tile- forced projection 3857 ( we use in the app), you can see these gaps when you start zooming but in 4326 the gaps appear only on the last zoom

Comment: Using EPSG:4326 works fine, for other EPSG no